# Redirect https to non http and Http to Https in directory with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to make my homepage to redirect to non https if it https
if `https://example.com` will redirect to `http://example.com`
and i want to make directory with ssl (just directory using SSL)

if `http://example.com/directory` wil redirect to `https://example.com/directory`

I'm use this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but it just show loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/dir
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dir
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: can you tell me,why it redirect to `example.com.com` ? :(

Comment: Clear your cache and try again. Your rule are permanent redirect, they're probably cached!

Comment: @japarS use an absolute path for your js and css. eg : **/file.css**